# How to change the color into red if the value that from database is unpaid or 0(in binary)?

Tags: php, html, css

I just wanted to change the color of the text here if the status is unpaid.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bill_record");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
      echo $row['bill_id'];
      echo "<p>".$row['status']."</p>"; // Status has a paid and unpaid 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add an else statement or paid values:

```
if ($row['status'] == 'unpaid') {
    echo "<p style=\"color: red\">".$row['status']."</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>".$row['status']."</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bill_record");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

  echo $row['bill_id'];

  if ($row['status'] == 'unpaid') {
    echo "<p style=\"color: red\">".$row['status']."</p>";
  }

}
```

Comment: why not do the color change in javascript ?